# VueJS: Error in mounted Third party component

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to integrate third-party component [Adaptive card](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards)  in my application using VueJs but getting following error when wrapping it inside a separate component so that I can re-use it in other places.

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this._card.onExecuteAction is not a
>   function"

I've created a [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2kmk7572r) to show the work done so far, can anyone suggest what I'm missing here.

I just need to integrate this adaptive card in my project as a reusable component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you are trying to call `onExecuteAction` function, instead of assigning it. It can be fixed, like this: `this._card.onExecuteAction = action => this.$emit("action", action);`

ps. i suggest you need also use `:card="card"` in your component template definition in `TodoLis.vue` and then add something like `@action="handleAction"` to it, to handle events emitted by your component.

Comment: Thanks for the help.